# How to compute only urban area from the give code

Tags: google-earth-engine, modis, land-cover

'land_and_cover_type_1" class has 1-16 whare "Urban and built-up" has the valus 13 with color code a5a5a5 i only want to compute the urban part of land insted of whole 1-16 value how to do that

[image: [gdescription here]

```
 var modisLandcover = ee.Image('MODIS/051/MCD12Q1/2001_01_01')
   .select('Land_Cover_Type_1');
   //var modisurban= modisLandcover.select('a5a5a5');
//print(modisurban);
// A pallete to use for visualizing landcover images.
var landcoverPalette = [
    'aec3d4', // water
    '152106', '225129', '369b47', '30eb5b', '387242', // forest
    '6a2325', 'c3aa69', 'b76031', 'd9903d', '91af40',  // shrub, grass, savanah
    '111149', // wetlands
    '8dc33b', // croplands
    'cc0013', // urban
    '6ca80d', // crop mosaic
    'd7cdcc', // snow and ice
    'f7e084', // barren
    '6f6f6f'  // tundra
];

    // A set of visualization parameters using the landcover palette.
    var landcoverVisualization = {palette: landcoverPalette, min: 0, max: 17, format: 'png'};
    // Center over our region of interest.
    //Map.centerObject(geometry, 11);
    // Draw the MODIS landcover image.
    Map.addLayer(modisLandcover, landcoverVisualization, 'MODIS landcover');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can apply a mask like this:

```
var urban = modisLandcover.updateMask(modisLandcover.eq(13))
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/e34c51debe5223156aaae87b991b7461